# Elixir .exs script "module is not loaded and could not be found" when using Mix

Tags: shell, module, erlang, elixir-mix, elixir

I have a .exs script in my root directory that I want to be able to execute on the command line like `elixir my_script.exs`. My script was working before I initialized Mix in my project but now it does not work. I can see that Mix is placing the .beam files in the `ebin/` directory but apparently my script is not looking in there.

What is the proper way to load custom modules into a .exs script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run script like: `mix run my_script.exs`

OR

```
mix compile
elixir -pa ebin/ my_script.exs
```